# clojurescript re-frame CSS link path changing with URL

Tags: html, css, clojurescript, re-frame

I have a trouble with the import of my CSS - which is made through the html link tag.
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">`

It works well when the url has got a single slash - like `http://url/page`.
it correctly look for the css at `http://url/styles/main.css`

but when the URL comports two slashes like `http://url/page/1` then the css is looked at:
`http://url/page/styles/main.css` and so is not found cause path is incorrect.

I am using clojurescript react-js wrapper called re-frame.

How to tell the soft to always look at `http://url/styles/main.css` whatever the URL.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your `<link ...>` is using a relative URL. Relative to the current page, that is.

Just change it to an absolute one by adding `/` at the front - `"/styles/main.css"`.

Comment: Indeed it was that easy... cheers